# How to backup an Azure PostgreSQL Single Server instance which is available on a private endpoint with Azure Backup Vault

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-backup

I'd like to back up an Azure PostgreSQL Single Server instance using the Azure Backup Vault, which is only available through a Private Endpoint. I've created the Backup Vault and the Backup Instance inside it, but I'm encountering the following error:

[image: Azure Backup instance error]

> **Message:** Failed to authenticate the database user. This may happen if the credentials (username and/or password) in the key vault are incorrect or the specified user does not have login access.
> **Recommendations:** Ensure that the credentials stored as part of the secret value in the key vault are valid. Ensure that the specified database user has login access. Refer to aka.ms/UserErrorDBUserAuthFailed for details.

I used this example code to create the backup instance with Terraform AzureRM Provider: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_protection_backup_policy_postgresql

The credentials stored in the key vault are:

```
❯ terraform console
> module.azure-infrastructure.foobar
"Server=<server-name>.postgres.database.azure.com;Database=<database>;Port=5432;User Id=<database>@<server-name>.postgres.database.azure.com;Password=<password>;Ssl Mode=Require;"
```

The username and password are correct (I'm 100% sure), as we run a few services in a private network that can connect to the database using these credentials. In the database logs, I cannot see any authentication failure during the backup's time.

My current hunch is that the Backup Vault cannot reach a database instance that is only available through a private endpoint. I think this because if I try to log into the PostgreSQL server with intentionally wrong credentials, the following is written to the log:

```
password authentication failed for user \"dbadmin\"
```

However, nothing similar is written to the log when the backup is trying to run. Any idea on how to make the backup run inside the private network?

Or how to back up an Azure PostgreSQL Single Server database that runs in a private network?

Thanks,

Comment: Has the database user/backup user  been granted with the `backup privileges` on the server.?

Comment: @Turdie the dbadmin user should have all the priviliges shouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know, don't make assumptions but verify when troubleshooting. Owh and try to create the key vault secret manually according to the docs instead of TF

Comment: @Turdie yeah, if I create the backup from the Azure UI (and assign all policies which it assings) then the DB becomes publicly available - after this the backup succeeds. If I deny public network access for the database, then the backup fails again :\

Comment: Sounds like a case for Microsoft Support